# How to deal with the error "cannot resolve symbol .."

Tags: scala

how can deal with this problem? i want call a function in this() constructor
 i use intellij idea as my IDE
here is my code:

```
def this(A:String, B, String) {
    this()
    val items = A.spilt(" ")
    for (elem <- item) {
      val dn = Function1(elem)
      Function2(dn) // here appears "cannot resolve symbol Function2"
    }
}
def Function2(dn:Type) {
......
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that "spilt" is a valid function. Are you thinking about [split](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps) ?

Secondly, Function2 does not accept a String as parameter, but a type. What is the definition of Function1 ? In order to work, it has to be defined with something like this :

```
// Notice the type of the argument
def Function1(s:String) = String.type // or any type, but this looks strange
```

Finally, you could easily refactor this code and make it more functional :

```
def this(A:String, B, String) {
    this()
    val items = A.split(" ").map(Function1).map(Function2)
}

def Function2(dn:Type) {
......
}
```

Comment: first, thanks for your answer, this really solve my question.

Comment: Second, yes "spilt" is my spell error, i am really sorry for this.

Comment: No problem, we're all here to learn :) Don't forget to close the question.

Comment: moreover, Function1 has defined in my Code.

Answer (score 0):

Method `Function2` accepts arguments of type `Type` but you try to call it with `dn` argument, which is of type `Function1`. So compiler can't find method with name `Function2` and argument type `Function1`.